# mod-rewrite: url-rewrite in .htaccess does not work

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite URLs from my-custom-url.com/abc/admin/anypage/ to my-custom-url.com/def/admin/anypage/

I have already taken a look to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html, chapter "Moved Document Root"

I opened .htaccess in root directory (which refers to http://www.my-custom-url.com/), looked for `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and included the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule   ^/abc/admin/$  /def/admin/  [R]
```

I tried also:

```
RewriteRule /abc/admin/ /def/admin/
```

Both didn't work. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, take shure, that you are allowed to use .htaccess and modRewrite

To take shure:
write some nonsenss in your .htaccess eg asdfasdf as fasdfa 
This should exec an Internal Server Error When you get the error, delete the nonsenss .-)

Then try this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^test-the-world/$ http://www.google.de [L]
RewriteRule ^abc/admin/$ /def/admin/ [R,L]
```

Then open the URI's:

http://example.com/test-the-world/ -> when successful you go tho google.de

http://example.com/abc/admin/  ->when successful you go to /def/admin/